# How to all possible ways in which any combination of n elements m times can be added to give a result

Tags: algorithm

This is kind of an extension to this question:
[Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

The difference is that in the above-linked question, each number(from the set of options) would be counted one time. But what if **each number is allowed to be chosen multiple times**? For example, if the given set of options is {1, 4, 9}, to get a total of 15, we can do any of the following:

```
a) 1*15
b) 4*3 + 1*2
c) 4*2 + 1*7
d) 4*1 + 1*11
e) 9*1 + 4*1 + 1*2
f) 9*1 + 1*6
```

Comment: As in the linked question, and based upon your examples, I assume you mean only *additions* of the numbers?

Comment: Yes, only addition @lurker

Comment: Well, it's trivial to modify the code given in the link. Remove `remaining = numbers[i+1:]` and change `subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n]) ` to `subset_sum(numbers, target, partial + [n])`. You can do the work to change the redundant sequences like `1,1,1,1,1,1,1` to `1*7`.

Comment: This looks like coin change problem to me. [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked all the possible combinations and not the best one so simple recursion can be used to obtain the results. The main idea is to:

```
1. Sort the array(non-decreasing).
2. First remove all the duplicates from array.
3. Then use recursion and backtracking to solve
```

A c++ solution for your problem:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void getNumbers(vector<int>& ar, int sum, vector<vector<int> >& res,vector<int>& r, int i) {

    if (sum < 0)
        return;

    if (sum == 0)
    {
        res.push_back(r);
        return;
    }

    while (i < ar.size() && sum - ar[i] >= 0)
    {

       r.push_back(ar[i]); 


        getNumbers(ar, sum - ar[i], res, r, i);
        i++;
        r.pop_back();
    }
}

vector<vector<int> > getSum(vector<int>& ar, int sum)
{
    sort(ar.begin(), ar.end());

    ar.erase(unique(ar.begin(), ar.end()), ar.end());

    vector<int> r;
    vector<vector<int> > res;
    getNumbers(ar, sum, res, r, 0);

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> ar;
    ar.push_back(1);
    ar.push_back(4);
    ar.push_back(9);

    int n = ar.size();

    int sum = 15; 
    vector<vector<int> > res = getSum(ar, sum);

    if (res.size() == 0)
    {
        cout << "Emptyn";
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
    {
        if (res[i].size() > 0)
        {
            cout << " ( ";
            for (int j = 0; j < res[i].size(); j++)
                cout << res[i][j] << " ";
            cout << ")";
        }
    }
}
```